# how to read cookie value in cakephp view file

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

in this i write the cookie value in controller file.
i wanna read that cookie value in view file  than how it possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must read it in the controller and set the value to make it available to the view:

```
$this->set('myValue', $this->Cookie->read('cookieValue'));
```

Then in the view, you can access the variable $myValue to return the value of 'cookieValue':

```
<?php echo $myValue; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

After all CakePHP is a PHP framework, you can read them by $_COOKIE :)

Bear in mind that you should use:

```
$this->Cookie->write('myValue', $value, false);
```

in your controller, because otherwise it will be encrypted and it will be hard to use :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Cookie components in AppController:

```
$components = array('Cookie');
```

Define following in AppController's beforeFilter():

```
$this->set('cookieHelper', $this->Cookie);
```

So that you could use it in view:

```
$cookieHelper->read('something');
```

Comment: While I understand why the chosen answer is "use it in the controller," I like that this is an option. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

I use the [SessionComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/view/173/Sessions) and [SessionHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/484/Session) to do this:

In the controller:

```
$this->Session->write('first_visit', true);
```

In the view:

```
if ($session->check('first_visit')) {
    $session->del('first_visit');
    echo $this->element('quick_intro');
}
```

You can also use $session->read('value') to read out a value from the session, instead of just checking if it exists.

Comment: The question is about Cookie rather than Session.