# cakephp: Cookie does not read at view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

in controller i try this, and print $cookieee,its give me array

```
$this->Cookie->write('User', $cookie, true, '+2 weeks');

$cookieee = $this->Cookie->read('User')
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cookieee);
echo "</pre>";
```

but 
My question

## when i print it any view file ,it doesnt print any values.

i try to print it by using below

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cookie);
echo "</pre>";
echo $cookie['username']."=cokie=";
```

and

```
$cookieee = $this->Cookie->read('User');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cookieee);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Read in controller and set in some variable !! Check this ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264498/how-to-read-cookie-value-in-cakephp-view-file

Comment: i know it but its not proper way.

Comment: What is the "proper way" then?

Comment: Why are you spelling "Cookie" differently every time you use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your view does not have access to the cookie.. Basically $this is referring to two different things in the case of your controller and your view.. thus basically set it in a model that is passed to the view i.e viewmodel and then use that in your view.

Not famililar with PHP hence no code but this is my understanding based on using MVC framework in .NEt

I guess this question tells you how to do the same in PHP: [how to read cookie value in cakephp view file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264498/how-to-read-cookie-value-in-cakephp-view-file)

and if you want to break the MVC pattern here you could use: `$_COOKIE[<cookie_name>]`.

Comment: i know it but its not proper way

Comment: I am sorry but this is the best way to achieve separation of concerns tomorrows if someone decides to get rid of cookie and use session (or something else likes) then  consider the issues you would face

Comment: use `$_COOKIE[<cookie_name>]` then

Comment: Hello. Why Cake doesn't have CookieHelper ? Does it conflicts with MVC architecture ? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Cookie helper in CakePHP, neither a method to access it in View.

You might want to set the cookie **to a variable** in controller, and then access that variable in corresponding view.

Comment: but when a page is cached, imposible to read cookie from controller.