# CakePHP reaching cookies from the view files

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies

I need to reach my cookies from the view files. I'm aware that one can use CookieComponent inside a controller and pass cookie values to view files with `set()`.

Visitors of our website has an options page. User's selections are saved to cookies. Up to now I was using CookieComponent and checking the values and making my works with that values. But now I added new options choices, so I need to reach them from my view files, or from my helpers. If I pass cookie values from the controller to view, I must do that for each of my action and I don't prefer it. Also it will make more complex code.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264498/how-to-read-cookie-value-in-cakephp-view-file) and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525428/cakephp-cookie-does-not-read-at-view). (Also it is possible to read them with `$_COOKIE[<cookie_name>]`, but that solution can't be used for encrypted cookies. My cookie is not encrypted but it can be in future)

My question is why there is no CookieHelper in the Cake's libs ? Is that a bad practice to reach cookies from the view files ? Is there a methodical way to reach cookies from views ?  For example writing a custom helper that uses `$_COOKIE` and use that helper ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing the data from the controller is an appropriate way of doing this.

If you need the data in many/all views, use the [`Controller::beforeFilter()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3abeforeFilter) callback, that way the variable is available to all views rendered by the specific controller:

```
class MyController extends AppController
{
    // ...

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFiler();

        $this->set('cookie', $this->Cookie->read('cookie'));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Just make sure that possible [cookie component configuring](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html#controller-setup) is done *before* reading the cookie!

Comment: While I agree this is correct, it's the same as provided in the answers he'd already found.  If the answer is "you can't", then that would seem more of a correct answer than repeating what the OP already said he knew.

Comment: @Dave What he found, or what he thinks he found, was that he has to set the value in each controller action, and for obvious reasons he didn't liked that. This answer shows how to avoid this problem by using the `beforeFilter()` callback, so at least according to his question this is something he didn't knew about. It's indeed mentioned [in one of the linked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15427749/1392379), though without further explanation that this makes the value available in all views. Feel free to add an answer that shows other working ways of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can access it via the [SessionHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html#sessionhelper):

```
echo $this->Session->read($cookieName);
```

Comment: You can in case you explicitly wrote the cookie data into the session, otherwise you won't find anything there.

Answer (score 0):

You can read cookie by help of javascript if this does not work use ajax calls to read cookies on document load and implement your logic by returning via json.